# How to use sub on a vector in R?

Tags: r

Consider this R code and output:

```
> the_string <- "a, b, c"
> the_vec <- strsplit(the_string, ",")
> str(the_vec)
List of 1
 $ : chr [1:3] "a" " b" " c"
> str(sub("^ +", "", the_vec))
 chr "c(\"a\", \" b\", \" c\")"
```

Looks like sub returns a single character array instead of a vector of character arrays. I'm hoping for:

```
chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

How do I get that?

**Edit**: the_string will come from users, so I want to tolerate a variable number of spaces, zero to many.

**Edit**: the tokens may have spaces in the middle that should be preserved.  So, `"a,    b  c,d"` should result in `c('a', 'b  c', 'd')`.

Comment: `str(sub("^ +", "", the_vec[[1]]))`

Comment: @HubertL If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strsplit` creates a list where each element is a vector of the split of each item in the original vector, eg.:

```
strsplit( c("a, b, c", "d, e"), ",")
[[1]]
[1] "a"  " b" " c"

[[2]]
[1] "d"  " e"
```

Here you only have one item in the input vector, so the result is all in the first item of the list:

```
the_string <- "a, b, c"
the_list <- strsplit(the_string, ",")
sub("^ +", "", the_list[[1]])
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

If you don't use `[[1]]` or `unlist`, `the_list` is coerced to a character vector using `as.character`:

```
as.character(the_list)
[1] "c(\"a\", \" b\", \" c\")"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
the_string <- "a, b, c"
the_vec <- unlist(strsplit(the_string, ", "))
```

If you add the space after the comma and unlist the entire thing you get the vector.

**Update:**

If the string has a varying amount of space between characters, I would remove all of the excess spaces and then run the same as above.  I chose 5 but maybe your string has more.  Also I added a second step to split characters that do not have a comma in between characters.

```
a <- "a, b,  c,   d,    e, f    g, h,i"
a <- gsub("( {2,5})", " ",a)
a <- unlist(strsplit(a, ", |,"))
unlist(strsplit(a, " "))


[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
```

Comment: yeah, but i want to tolerate a variable number of spaces

Comment: I would suggest removing all of the extra spaces in an entire string before splitting by the comma.

Comment: If this is a csv, you could also import the whole thing with `read.csv("file", strip.white = T)` to remove the extra spaces around the strings.

Comment: Thanks, it's not a csv. Also, I can't remove all the spaces because a value might have a space in the middle. So: "a, b c, d" should result in a vector c("a", "b c", "d").

Comment: This is a very different question than was originally posted.  You may want to update the post to reflect the complexity of the problem you are trying to solve.  Having a comma that separates all of the values is essential in a `strsplt`.  Additionally the `gsub` I updated the response does not remove the spaces but reduces all spaces up to 5 characters down to one.  This might be the first step in a few steps to get to where you want.  The second command after the `unlist`/`strsplt` may be another `strsplt(a, " ")` where you split any remaining concatenated characters

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem, hopefully, it doesn't get too much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

One base-R solution

```
lapply(the_vec, function(x) sub("^ +", "", x))[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```